# Push the output of a for loop into an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to push the output of a **for** loop into an array but I am not being able to do so. Following is the code that I have written:

```
<?php
$n = 14;
for ($i = 2; $i <= $n; $i++) 
{ 
    for ($j = 2; $j <= $n; $j++) 
    { 
        if ($i%$j == 0) // if remainder of $i divided by $j is equal to zero, break. 
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($i == $j) // 
    {
        $form = $i;
        //echo $form;
        $numArray = array();
        array_push($numArray, $form); // Here I am trying to push the contents from the `$form` variable into the `$numArray`
        print_r($numArray);                 
    }
}
?>
```

The output that I obtain through this is:

> Array ( [0] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 3 ) Array ( [0] => 5 ) Array ( [0] => 7 ) Array ( [0] => 11 ) Array ( [0] => 13 )

Here, we see that the array index basically remains the same, so it has no scope for future use. So, **how can I make this seem like as shown below**:

> Array ( [0] => 2 ) Array ( [1] => 3 ) Array ( [2] => 5 ) Array ( [3] => 7 ) Array ( [4] => 11 ) Array ( [5] => 13 )

Please note that, `$n` in the code can be any number less than 101 and greater than 1. Thank you for your precious time put into reading and trying to helping me out. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$numArray` should be declared once, not every time in the loop. And you can simply add value to the array by using expression like: `$numArray[] = $i;`
Try this code:

```
<?php

$numArray = array();
$n = 14;
for ($i = 2; $i <= $n; $i++) {
    for ($j = 2; $j <= $n; $j++) {
        if ($i % $j == 0) { // if remainder of $i divided by $j is equal to zero, break. 
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($i == $j) {
        $numArray[] = $i;
    }
}
print_r($numArray);
```

Comment: I am trying it out. Wait a second brother. :)

Comment: It worked. Btw, I tried to include the print_r($numArray) inside the for loop to watch out what happens next, and it output a weird result. :( . Loads of love, from India.

Comment: It will print array with elements 1 first time, 2 second time, 3 third time & so on.

Comment: I bet that is the exact reason why Lovepreet placed the print_r outside.

Comment: Right @Andreas.

Comment: But It worked even when I didn't declare the $numArray = array(); at the top. Any idea why it did work like that also?

Comment: Read the manual. Php does not require declaration of variables prior to usage, in most cases. `$i++` is an exception

Comment: OH. I got it now. Thanks @Andreas

Comment: PHP automatically initialize it while assigning values inside the loop `$numArray[] = $i;` here. But it's safe to declare and initialize above, in case if condition not true even once.